# why ruby upto method is so slow?

Tags: ruby

```
n = 5000000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("upto  :")   { for i in 1..n; 0.upto(( 10 )) ; end }
  x.report("range :")   { for i in 1..n; 0..10 ; end }
end
```

Results:

```
              user     system      total        real
upto   :     1.116440   0.068953   1.185393 (  1.187705)
range  :     0.156921   0.000000   0.156921 (  0.156759)
```

Why does upto() takes so much time compared to the manual range ?

Comment: Since `0.upto(10)` without a block creates an [enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html), the equivalent would be `(0..10).each` (which indeed gives similar results). And if you're actually iterating both variants by passing a block, i.e. `0.upto(10) { }` vs. `(0..10).each { }` they become identical in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This benchmark actually compares oranges to apples now: `upto` [performs the actual iterations](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/numeric.c#L5587) under the hood, while `0..10` is a range literal that causes only a creation of a tiny object per iteration (with no memory allocations).